# Markers are not loading using setMap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create jsp page with google map.There i am initializing google map like this..

```
 var map;
  var markersArray = [];
 function initialize()
{
    var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(8.3641835,77.252415);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom:9,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: chicago
    };
   map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas")
  ,mapOptions);
```

}

After response from one ajax call i am trying to adding markers on this google map

```
   function showOverlays() {
////alert("overlay");

  if (markersArray) {
    for (i in markersArray) {

      markersArray[i].setMap(map);
    }
  }
}
```

**But markers are not displaying in the google map**...What is the reason.Can anyone pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it was a problem with custom marker image.when i removed custom marker,it works

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't seem to be adding anything to `markersArray`, at least in the code you've given us.  Also nowhere do you seem to be creating markers.

However assuming that you are adding markers and pushing them into the array, then you merely have a simple mistake in your code.  Change the loop to this:

```
for (i in markersArray) {
  i.setMap(map);
}
```